# Issue with a reference including DOI entry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, doi

I am using elsarticle-harv.bst as my bst file which can be reached [here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle-harv.bst). When I include a reference with a DOI entry in the bib file, it shows adjacent to the page information as shown below. How can I have a gap between the page and DOI information?

[image]

Below I am sharing a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\newcounter{bibcount}
\begin{document}
\cite{cite}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

```
@article{cite,
  title={Title information},
  author={Smith, Joe and Kurtz, Marry},
  journal={{IEEE Journal}},
  year={2021},
  pages= {1--5},
  publisher={IEEE},
  doi= {10.2456/TR.2021.54782}
}
```

If I update the page information in the bib item as  `pages= {1--5. $ $}`, it does solve my issue, but clearly, it is not an efficient solution.

Comment: The code of `elsarticle-harv` has a few peculiarities that essentially mean that the style expects `@article` entries to have a `volume` field. If an `@article` entry misses the `volume`, the code used in the `.bst` file causes some weird side effects like this one. If at all possible try to give a `volume` field (or change the style). If you must use `elsarticle-harv` and cannot give a `volume` field, you can try fixing the `.bbl` file manually for a one-off. ...

Comment: ... I looked into changing the `.bst` file to allow for `@article`s without `volume`, but the code is quite complex and I don't quite understand why certain things are defined the way they are, so I cannot be sure that my attempts to fix this issue do not have bad side effects.

Comment: I am trying to cite papers published in IEEE. For some reason, no volume information is provided for certain papers. That's why I am using the DOI info.

Comment: DOI (Digital Object Identifier) is a "URL" to the official digital version (if it exists) of the document. It is not a replacement for the volume. Many papers you get handed e.g. by the author, or just get a paper copy, just don't show full information (volume, number, pages, month, year). Solution is to just dig into the archives of the journal and grab the missing data from there.

Comment: I'd have thought that most articles published in journals would still have a volume. Even many online-only journals still assign volume numbers, because many style guides still refer to volume numbers. I can imagine a situation where a journal does not yet assign a volume number for pre-published articles, in that case you might want to put a placeholder volume like `volume = {pre-publication},`. You can then fill in a real volume once the journal publishes the article properly and assigns a volume number. ...

Comment: ... As I said, you could try and fix the `.bst` file, but it is quite complex and at least to me some bits of the code are unclear, so changes are a bit dangerous. You are presumably using `elsarticle-harv` because you want to publish with Elsevier, so you should probably contact them about this: Let them know that you need to cite a paper without volume and that their style does not handle it properly.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. For now, I solved the problem by using the inefficient solution that I mentioned in the original post. I'll keep the question in case someone figures out how to solve it thru the ```.bst``` file.